# Callbacks that don't block

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I would like to write a function that takes a callback and calls it after the function is done.

This is easy:

```
var callback = function (ref) {
    var i = 1337;
    while (i--) {
        console.log(ref, 'callback');
    }
};

var someFoo = function (ref, callback) {
    console.log(ref, 'self');

    callback(ref);
}

someFoo('one', callback); // 1
someFoo('two', callback); // 2
```

But here I'm facing this problem: First the `someFoo` call blocks until the allback is finished. That means this code is equivalent to this (which blocks until each function is finished):

```
someFoo('one');
callback('one');
someFoo('two');
callback('two');
```

Now the question: How to make the callback call asynchronous?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change:

```
callback(ref);
```

To:

```
setTimeout(function(){ callback(ref); }, 0);
```

Or, since you are writing a chrome extension, and, therefore, don't have to worry about older browsers, you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
setTimeout(callback.bind(null, ref), 0);
```

Comment: This looks like dirty hack. Are there also some 'official' ways?

Comment: @WaleryStrauch Nope, the only other ways would be dirtier.

Comment: It's not a dirty hack. JavaScript code is synchronous as Mike Thompson answered. The only source of "asynchronous" execution is an outside influence(e.g. the browser responding to events or timers)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript as implemented in browsers is single-threaded so you cannot do a real asynchronous call. What you can do is something like this to approximate that:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    callback(ref);
}, 1000);
```

Where 1000 is 1 second in milliseconds (delay further as needed). However, as it is single-threaded that callback will still block other code that was running.

New browsers support [web workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/), but using web workers to approximate threading will leave you with code that won't work with many older browsers and not all newer browsers support the full spec even now.

Comment: It's chrome extension in my case, so I don't care about IE (or older browser)

Comment: I don't think the answer you selected really helps you because all it does is arbitrarily executes a piece of code at a given time within the same thread. You may just have to bite the bullet and keep tweaking until you find something more obviously synchronous that runs quickly.

Comment: @MikeThomsen `setTimeout` guarantees that the callback executes sometime after the current execution flow completes. That's how the Javascript event loop works. It's not arbitrary and it won't block any other code that was running, since it won't run until any other code (that's already started) completes.